# Material-UI , Radio Button + map function ( React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

so i need help guys, i want to replace the old radio button (classic)
with a new one using material-ui. i couldn't make it. 
please suggest a solution.
thx in advance. 
in pic u will see everything

```
class Question extends Component {
  render() {
    var that = this; // Funny way to be able to access this from inside our iterator() function below.
    var iterator = this.props.questionChoices.map(function(choice){
            return (
                <div className="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type= {that.props.questionType} name={that.props.questionID} value={choice}/>
                    {choice}
                </label>
                <RadioButtonGroup >
                    <RadioButton
                        value="ludicrous"
                        label={choice}
                        valueSelected={choice}
                        style={styles.radioButton}
                    />
                </RadioButtonGroup>
                </div>
              );
      });
    return (

            <div className="row">
                <div className="form">
                  <Paper zDepth={1} >
                  <div className="h3">
                    <h3 >{this.props.questionID} - {this.props.questionText}</h3>
                        {iterator}
                        </div>
                        </Paper>
                </div>
            </div>
    );
    }
```

}

[result of the problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzlr1.png)

Comment: sorry here i will post the whole code

Comment: var iterator = this.props.questionChoices.map(function(choice){ return (
                 <div className="radio">
     <label>
      <input type= {that.props.questionType} name={that.props.questionID} value={choice}/>
      {choice}
     </label><RadioButtonGroup >
      <RadioButton
             value="ludicrous"
       label={choice}
       valueSelected={choice}
             style={styles.radioButton}
           />
     </RadioButtonGroup>

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering the old radio button as well, you also need to define the selected value in the group component and render the group only once, currently you are rendering it for every option.

```
var iterator = (
  <RadioGroup value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
  {  this.props.questionChoices.map(choice =>
        <FormControlLabel value={choise} control={<Radio />} label={choise} />
    )
  }
  </RadioGroup>
);
```

Then you need to create the `handleChange` function to update the state.

```
class Question extends Component {
  state = {
    value: '',
  };

  handleChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ value });
  };
...
```

You can find a working example here: https://material-ui-next.com/demos/selection-controls/